# USB DAC support on ubuntu touch?

Tags: drivers, usb, sound, ubuntu-touch, alsa

The headphone jack on my aquarius m10 ubuntu edition is having issues (I have figued out that the right ear pin has trouble makeing contact with the headphone jack). I was wondering if ubuntu touch supports USB DACs so I can get one to replace the problamatic headphone jack as well as improving sound quality.